# Debugging is not working in VS code. after upgrading php version from 7.2 to 7.4

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, visual-studio-code, php-7.4

I have upgraded my PHP version from 7.2 to 7.4 and I found that debugging has stopped in all projects.

**My configurations are-**

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

I have added the above configuration in the following files-

- /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ni
- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ni
- /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini

**php -v command is returning the following output-**

```
PHP 7.4.14 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2021 08:04:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

**I have installed the Xdebug extension in VS code too-**

[image]

**phpinfo(); function is returning the following output-**

[image]

How should I do to resolve my issue?

Comment: First of all, you remove `s` in `xdebug.remote_port = 9000s`. Please tell me if you get the same issue?

Comment: I have removed the "s", still, it is not working.

Comment: Did you already restart apache after removing `s`?

Comment: Yes, I did, I restarted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PHP 7.4.14 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2021 08:04:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

If you use `Xdebug` with version `3`, you have to config again parameters. (https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#Step-Debugging). Based on the shared documentation, I will suggest the following config:

```
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

Comment: You're welcome. I upvote because your question is clear.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, great to connect with you.

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me one thing? Do I need to add this config in all 4 files (I have mentioned in the question)?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, @ThânLƯƠNG I also used the names of the wrong parameters that no longer exists on version 3.